# Problemas con reproducción de videos mp4 webM en navegadores moviles

Tags: html5, video, navegador-web, video-adaptativo

Quiero reproducir un video utilizo html5 para cargarlo en mi    documento, en el navegador de escritorio todo va bien incluso he    utilizado otro formatos y no tengo ningun problema pero el tratar de    reproducirlo en moviles solo carga como un segundo y se queda    detenido. Si añado la propiedad controls si puedo reproducirlo pero    al presionar el boton de play me lo lanza en una nueva pantalla cosa    que no busco quiero que se reproduzca en el mismo plano de toda mi    pagina web.

```
<div class="video-background-container">
        <video id="video " preload="auto" autoplay loop muted class="video-background">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/prueba-video.mp4"/>
        </video>
    </div>
```

este es el html que uso algo muy basico, añado los atributos autoplay por que como lo mencione necesito que en cuanto se cargue la pagina en el navegador también se cargue el video, lei por ahí que la propiedad muted era necesario en navegadores móviles al tratar de reproducir un video con html 5.
podrían ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, es necesario que el video no tenga sonido o que esté "muteado", y aparte debes agregar el atributo `playsinline`, o con el prefijo `webkit-playsinline` para mayor soporte en OS antiguos. [En el blog de Webkit podrás leer mas al respecto](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) (En inglés)

El código:

```
<div class="video-background-container">
    <video id="video " preload="auto" autoplay loop muted class="video-background" webkit-playsinline playsinline>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="path/al/video.mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

Probado en Safari para iOS, y Firefox para iOS, con iOS 11.2

Comment: Ha funcionado perfectamente amigo. Gracias por tu ayuda.